# Why TorchVision's GoogLeNet has this strange "normalization"?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I'm reading the source code of [TorchVision's GoogLeNet](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/googlenet.py) and I found these lines strange and can't figure it out.

```py
def _transform_input(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    if self.transform_input:
        x_ch0 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 0], 1) * (0.229 / 0.5) + (0.485 - 0.5) / 0.5
        x_ch1 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 1], 1) * (0.224 / 0.5) + (0.456 - 0.5) / 0.5
        x_ch2 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 2], 1) * (0.225 / 0.5) + (0.406 - 0.5) / 0.5
        x = torch.cat((x_ch0, x_ch1, x_ch2), 1)
    return x
```

I know that ImageNet datasets had `mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]` and `std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]` and it looks like some "normalization" but it is obviously not `(x - mean) / std` but more like `x * std + mean`. Also I don't know about the `0.5` thing.

Anyone who can explain these code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was done to match [TensorFlow's way of preprocessing the input image](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d0c80b81b8b58dbc7dd0880b5c261ab46541333e/research/slim/preprocessing/inception_preprocessing.py#L304-L305). In the pull request that added GoogLeNet to TorchVision, [the author explains that he matched the processing done by TensorFlow](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/678#issuecomment-470318912). Here is [the commit that added](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/678/commits/d30200509ee1aa4a20d7e4197c7f14ae72ed5eff#) the normalization in the question.

the author who contributed GoogLeNet to TorchVision wrote

> I've updated the code to match the structure required for the TensorFlow weights. Also added the input normalization used for the Inception v3 model.